# How to find duplicate rows by multiple columns and within a timeframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, duplicates, rows

For the example data frame below, I'm trying to get the rows where 'fruit' and 'animal' columns have the same value **and** the difference of the values of dateTime column is not greater than 10 minutes but I am having trouble with the last step. (For more details, the selected rows will eventually go into a separate df and be dropped from the current one).

**df_test:**

```
    dateTime                fruit   animal  number
1   08/01/2020 1:08:00 AM   apple   monkey  1
2   08/01/2020 1:05:00 AM   apple   monkey  4
3   08/01/2020 1:20:00 AM   apple   frog    3
4   08/01/2020 1:40:00 AM   pear    dog     1
5   08/01/2020 1:47:00 AM   apple   monkey  2
```

To get the rows where 'fruit and 'animal' both match I tried:

```
duplicates_df = df_test[df_test.duplicated(['fruit','animal'])]
```

After putting the duplicates in duplicates_df, I was not able to find what methods can be used to extract the ones that apply to the specified rule about dateTime. What are the ways to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
from datetime import timedelta
import itertools as itt

def processGroup(G):
    indexes = G.index.to_list()
    groups  = []
    for i1,i2 in itt.combinations(indexes, 2):
        added=False
        if (max(df.dateTime[i1] ,  df.dateTime[i2]) - min(df.dateTime[i1] ,  df.dateTime[i2])).seconds/60 <= 20.0:
            for g in groups:
                if (i1 in g) and (i2 not in g):
                    g.append(i2)
                    added=True
                    break
                elif (i2 in g) and (i1 not in g):
                    g.append(i1)
                    added=True
                    break
                elif (i2 in g) and (i1 in g):
                    added=True
                    break
                    
            if not added:
                groups.append([i1, i2])
                
#     print(groups)
    
    G['Group'] = ''
    result = pd.DataFrame(columns=G.columns.to_list())
    for i, g in enumerate(groups):
        result = pd.concat([result, G.loc[g]])
        result.loc[g, 'Group'] = (i+1)
    
    return result

RESULT = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns.to_list()+['Group'])

for i, g in df.groupby(['fruit', 'animal']):
#     print(g)
    RESULT = pd.concat([RESULT, processGroup(g)])
    
print(RESULT.set_index(['fruit', 'animal', 'Group']))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'am not sure if this answers your question

```
df.sort_values(by=['dateTime'], inplace=True)
cond = ((df[['fruit', 'animal']] == df[['fruit', 'animal']].shift()).all(axis=1)) & df.dateTime.diff().lt('10min')
df[~cond]
```

Comment: This is an insightful answer to see. I voted for the first answer though, just because I'm looking for the duplicates to be put in another data frame.